# Twitter created_at timestamp comparing it in php

Tags: php, twitter

In the twitter API each tweet has a timestamp a property of 
"created_at"

The format is "Sat Sep 17 14:48:57 +0000 2011";

The user should get a point every 24 hours for a tweet..

how will I do date compare with this timestamp in php?

```
$tweetTimestamp = strtotime('Sat Sep 17 14:48:57 +0000 2011');

if($tweetTimestamp > 84600) {
echo ' update tweet points';
}
else {
    echo ' no points';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time() - $tweetTimestamp` will give you the number of seconds that have passed since `$tweetTimestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tweetTimestamp = strtotime('Sat Sep 17 14:48:57 +0000 2011');

if(time() - $tweetTimestamp > 84600) {
echo ' update tweet points';
}
else {
    echo ' no points';
}
```